# Does Miller Rabin algorithm becomes faster if $a$ is choosen from the set $\mathbb{Z}_n^*-(\mathbb{Z}_n-\{0\})$ rather than randomly

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, primality-test

In *[Miller-Rabin Primality Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test)* for $n$ we  first represent $n-1$ as $u\times2^k$ and then random choose some $a$ from the set $\{2 ,3 \cdots n-2\}$ and then we compute $b_0(=a^u),b_1(=b_0^2)\cdots b_{k-1},b_k$ (all computations are modulo $n$) and then test for various conditions.
My question is - rather than randomly choosing $a$ cant we choose such $a$ whose probability of being a *A-Witness* is higher.
Since $W_n^F \subset W_n^A$ i.e. every Fermat Witness is a A-Witness and $\mathbb{Z}_n^*-(\mathbb{Z}_n-\{0\})$ contains Fermat's Witness. So if we choose $a$ from this set, isn't the algorithm will be faster in case $n$ is composite.